# android - refresh parent Activity when child Activity finishes

Tags: android, android-activity, parent-child, up-navigation

I have a parent Activity which starts a child activity.

In the child activity, I do:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Ride");
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

When I click the Home/Up button, I `finish` the activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And in addition, I do `finish` In one more place in the **Child Activity**, and in both places where I have the `finish`,  it goes back to the **Parent Activity**.

**My question:**

My problem is that I want to refresh the **Parent Activity** only in the case of **one** of the `finishes`.

When I do the finish **not from the Up button** - the data in the Parent Activity **changes**, so - When I press the Back/Up button, there is no need to refresh the **Parent**, but when I do the other `finish`, I want to refresh the **Parent**.

How can I detect that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: how to make an activity return results to the activity which calls it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785806/android-how-to-make-an-activity-return-results-to-the-activity-which-calls-it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start child activity as

```
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
```

And in case on up button set result as success in child activity and in case of backpress set result as failure.

And in `onActivityResult(..)` of parent activity get the status and kill the parent activity in the desired case.

Answer (score 3):

*In Parent Activity*

```
startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int REQUEST_CODE);
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
case RESULT_OK:
    //refresh parentAcitivty  
    //get the result from the Up button back
    //e.g adapter.notifydatasetchanged()
case RESULT_CANCEL:
    //Do nothing 
    //return from childActivity by other finishes
```

*In ChildActivity*

```
case 1: //**from the Up button**
   setResult(RESULT_CANCEL);
   finish();
case 2: //**do the other finish**
   setResult(RESULT_OK)；
   finish();
```

I hope the code will give you a hint.

Answer (score 3):

in this case, use `onResume`.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // your code (for example: initialize(); etc.. )
}
```

If you refer to this article, you will understand why.

[activity life cycle Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484493/activity-life-cycle-android)

Answer (score 2):

You have finish() method in two places as described. One is the back button on the ActionBar (let it be called **AbBack**) and the other one in one some other place (**RandomBack**).

Let **A** be the main Activity be **B** be the child Activity.

In A instead of startActivity() method, use

```
startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int REQUEST_CODE);
```

This is done so that, Activity B when it finishes can return data to this activity, and depending upon the data you can refresh/not-refresh

So in **Activity B**,

In the case of **AbBack**, call this method *setResult(RESULT_OK)*; and for **RandomBack**, call *setResult(RESULT_CANCELED)*;

Finally in Activity **A**, you have to override the method

`onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, In`tent data)

where you can compare resultCode == RESULT_OK and if so, that means data is from **AbBack** or if not it's from **RandomBack**, and do the required refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [navigateUpFromTask()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html#navigateUpTo%28android.app.Activity,%20android.content.Intent%29)

Answer (score 0):

Use NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this); onBackPressed function like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
}
```